# from "p" to a "list"

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Good day!

I am using WordPress and this plugin outputs products in one p tag and separates them with a semicolon [as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRmuc.png).

I was wondering if it is possible somehow to take the values of that p tag and output them **in a list**? One under the other?

Or perhaps this is a JavaScript question? Or maybe even I should fiddle with the WordPress plugin itself?

I will appreciate any help or hints!

Thanks

Comment: you can do via custom code. Please share me the link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple script like this to extract the text content of p, separate each entry after each semicolon and map with `p` tags:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector("dd.variation-bundledProducts")

const elems = document.querySelector("dd.variation-bundledProducts p").textContent.split(";").map(el => `<p>${el}</p>`).join("");

parent.innerHTML = elems
```

```html
<dd class="variation-bundledProducts">
  <p>
    element1; element2; element3; element4
  </p>
</dd>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising! Now only the question where should I place this script. and I guess I don't need the "parent.innerHTML = elems" line, only the first two, right? and remove the "dd." right? Should I place the script in the head or the footer or just a snippet on wordpress? Thanks! My first time adding custom js to a wordpress site :)

Comment: You can place the the code inside a `<script></script>` tag before the closing `</body>` tag. You need all three lines, I used the <dd> tag with taht class since that's what appears in the image you linked. You are free to change the parent and children selectors with the selectors that you prefer.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I place the code where you advised me to - there is no effect. I must be doing something wrong or WordPress or some plugins interfere with it. :/

Comment: Sorry I don't have a magic crystall ball to be able to guess what's going on in your particular case, you need to try to make some logs and check first of all if the script is executed.

Comment: I totally understadn that. Thank you for your time and patience, I will see what I can do :)